# myRailsApp - PostgreSQL FATAL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new with ruby and coding in general, I'm working on a ruby on rails project and PostgreSQL is giving me an error:  FATAL:role "myRailsApp" does not exist. googled for posible solutions and couldn't find anything. thanks

Comment: Check your db config. `myRailsApp` should probably be `postgres`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a role with that name created in the Postgres DBMS. If you are new, you probably should download Pgadmin (http://www.pgadmin.org/), there you can configure your postgres database.
When you open it you will see your servers and stuff, loof for the 'Login roles' part and create a new role that can create databases (That role needs to have the same user and password you chose on the configuration file)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wvDVBjNDys